# Unable to get session varibale after redirect to another domain

Tags: php, session, cross-domain, session-variables, session-cookies

I have created session on one page and unable to get these session on another page, how can I able to get session on another page.

page1.php

```
$_SESSION['access_token']        = "token";
$_SESSION['access_secret']       = "secret";
$_SESSION['session_handle']      = "handle";
header("Location: mydomain/page2.php");
```

page2.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
     echo $_SESSION['access_token'];
} else {
    echo "";
}
```

I have tried above code with same domain or different domain.

Comment: If "one page" and "another page" really are on different domains, then you cannot access the same session. Sessions are host specific. You'd have to hand over all session details in the redirect and create a new session from that. Not exactly a convenient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `session_start();`in page1.php (on first line). If the domains are different will not work

Answer (score 0):

If first page and second page are on different domains then it can't be done because sessions are stored on the server.You can't pass it from one domain to another domain.

Otherwise If both the pages are on the same server then it could be because you didn't start the session in first page.